# Android: how to listen for scrolling events?

Tags: android, scrollview

is there a way to establish a listener on the process of scrolling in a ScrollView or a HorizontalScrollView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only create a class that extends ScrollView and override the onScrollChanged() method.

Comment: Yes, use the fully qualified class name. `<com.example.MyView ...>`

Comment: No such method. Overriding scrollTo(), however, does the trick.

Comment: Yes, there is such a method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)